# Streaming MP4 with Express and connect-stream

Tags: node.js, express, video, mp4

I currently have developped a small nodejs server to serve MP4 videos.
To transmit it i use Express and the connect-stream library.

But when i go to the videos URL (1 URL per video) some video start right away and some doesn't start at all (Under Chrome).

They're all encoded with H264/AAC.

The only thing i see different on the client side is that for the videos that won't play, there is a HTTP 304 sent.

I tried to block etag and set cache-control header to no cache but still, nothing is working.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance !

EDIT:

304 is not an error so I backup Etag configuration. But still the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was found within s3fs implementation, S3 is used to store the video and it is not good with streaming. I implemented a RAM cache with a bash process to put/delete videos chunk in RAM